# How to write an F# union type chooser?

Tags: f#

Is there a better way to do this if F#?

```
type T =
    | A of int
    | B of string
    static member chooseA x = match x with A i -> Some i | _ -> None
    static member chooseB x = match x with B s -> Some s | _ -> None
```

The usecase is the following:

```
let collection = [A 10; B "abc"]
let aItems = collection |> Seq.choose T.chooseA
let bItems = collection |> Seq.choose T.chooseB
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? What's not satisfactory in your current solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what would be better. I was hoping that there is a way to do this without the boilerplate code.The best would be if I don't have to write anything but instead chooseA and chooseB would be defined automatically :)

Answer (score 3):

Use List.partition to split your source elements:

```
type T =
    | A of int
    | B of string

let collection = [A 10; B "abc"; A 40; B "120"]

let result = List.partition (function | A _ -> true | _ -> false) collection

val result : T list * T list = ([A 10; A 40], [B "abc"; B "120"])
```

Then you can use fst and snd to select the relevant lists.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work with union types which have more than 2 constructors

Comment: No, in that case you should use Seq.groupBy<'T, 'Key> instead (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee370445(v=vs.120).aspx). You would still have to unravel the result sequence or pipe it to Map.ofSeq.

Answer (score 1):

This is awkward, but I can see why it is not an important case F#'s design. Usually, there is a solution that allows for a complete pattern match instead of multiple, somewhat incomplete ones. For example, the two concrete item sequences can be constructed like this:

```
let aItems, bItems =
    let accA, accB = ResizeArray(), ResizeArray()
    collection |> Seq.iter (function A i -> accA.Add i | B s -> accB.Add s)
    seq accA, seq accB
```

*A similar solution without mutation can be made if you dislike it, but I see little reason to worry about encapsulated mutation. Note that the results are cast to `seq`.*

This uses pattern matching in the manner it is designed for:

- If another case is added to `T`, a warning will appear in the handling function, which is exactly where editing should continue: determining how to treat the new input case.
- The program doesn't needlessly iterate the input multiple times for each kind of input, but rather goes over it once and handles each item when first encountered.

---

If the above isn't suitable, you can still shorten the question's code a bit by using the `function` keyword and declaring the chooser function as a lambda. For example:

```
let aItems = collection |> Seq.choose (function A i -> Some i | _ -> None)
```

Note that this is lazy, just like the proposal in the question: here, every iteration over `aItems` will needlessly iterate over all the `B` cases in the input.

Comment: The code still doesn't look nice. I was hoping for some elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the following variant:

```
open System.Reflection

type T =
    | A of int
    | B of string

let collection = [A 10; B "abc"; A 40; B "120"]

let sp (col: T list) (str:string) = 
      if col=[] then []
      else  
        let names = "Is" + str
        col |> List.filter(fun x-> let t = x.GetType()
                                   if t.GetProperty(names) = null then false
                                   else 
                                   t.InvokeMember(names, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, x, null) :?> bool)
            |> List.map(fun y ->
                y.GetType().InvokeMember("get_Item", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, y, null))

sp collection "A" |> printfn "%A\n"
sp collection "B" |> printfn "%A\n"   
sp collection "C" |> printfn "%A\n"
```

Print:

```
[10; 40]

["abc"; "120"]

[]
```

http://ideone.com/yAytQk

I'm new to F#, so I think that can be done easier

Comment: Thanks! It's a nice exercise but not something to use in production.